# Transcribing ASCII maze into graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, maze

I have a maze such as the below:

```
XXXOOOOX
OXXXOXOE
OXXOOXXO
OSXOXXXO
XOOOXOOO

//X = wall
//O = path
//S = startpoint
//E = endpoint
```

I want to transcribe this to a graph (adjacency matrix) but am unsure in my attempt to do so. An adjacency matrix is a list of lists of booleans, with true representing a takeable path and false representing an impossible path (eg. `(0,-1)` in the maze cannot connect to `(7,-1)` (0,0 being the top-left most node)). I'm not sure how to transcribe this, my best guess would be to take each element in a list and then a sublist with connecting nodes. It's difficult to process given the size of this maze, so here's a smaller one:

```
X E || A B
S O || C D
```

Would an adjacency matrix be below for the above maze (1 = true, 0 = false)?

```
  A B C D
A 0 0 0 0
B 0 0 0 1
C 0 0 0 1
D 0 1 1 0

//C connects to D (start)
//D connects to B (end)
```

It's just really confusing, I'm not sure how to map an x,y (sometimes z, too) co-ordinate to a graph.

Comment: general approach would be: for every pair (x,y) of coordinates, check if both (x,y) and (x-1,y) are passable. if so, put in a true. same for all other  neighbors of (x,y). Everything that is not a neighbor, gets a false by default.

Comment: @Sirko, for a maze of n*m dimensions, should the adjacency matrix be n^2 elements wide and m^2 elements deep?

Comment: for an `m*n` maze, you would have `(m*n)` nodes, resulting in a `(m*n) * (m*n)` adjacency matrix. Probably an adjacency list would be the better approach here, as your matrix would be very sparse.

Comment: @riista [this](https://github.com/jfhbrook/jfhbrook.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2010-11-19-maze-adjacency-matrix.md) might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 static void set(boolean[][] paths, int cols, int row0, int col0, int row1, int col1) {
     int index0 = row0 * cols + col0;
     int index1 = row1 * cols + col1;
     paths[index0][index1] = paths[index1][index0]= true;
 }

 static boolean[][] paths(String[] maze) {
     int rows = maze.length;
     int cols = maze[0].length();
     boolean[][] paths = new boolean[rows * cols][rows * cols];
     for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
         for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
             if (maze[i].charAt(j) == 'X')
                 continue;
             if (i + 1 < rows && maze[i + 1].charAt(j) != 'X')
                 set(paths, cols, i, j, i + 1, j);
             if (j + 1 < cols && maze[i].charAt(j + 1) != 'X')
                 set(paths, cols, i, j, i, j + 1);
         }
     }
     return paths;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     String[] maze = {
         "XXXOOOOX",
         "OXXXOXOE",
         "OXXOOXXO",
         "OSXOXXXO",
         "XOOOXOOO",
     };
     boolean[][] paths = paths(maze);
     for (boolean[] row : paths) {
         for (boolean cell : row)
             System.out.print(cell ? "1" : "0");
         System.out.println();
     }
 }
```